# Recyclerview inside linearlayout scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a screen which has one tool bar information of a product and list of similar products.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<toolbar />
<Scrollbar>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ProductInfo />
        <TextView > <!--Similar products -->
        <RecyclerView />
    </LinearLayout>
</Scrollbar>
```

Everything is working fine except scroll. Scroll is not smooth when recyclerview comes on screen. I think the idea should be to have recycler view without its own scrollbar. Because now it seems like i'm ending up with two scrollbars which is making scrolling painful.
Is there a way through which i can disable scrollbar of recyclerview and stretch it to to occupy required height and parent scrollbar scroll my screen smoothly?

I'm using staggeredGridLayoutManager so I can use both productinfo view and similar products as card in single Recyclerview, as ProductINfo will need complete width of the screen where as for similar product i need two column. 
Please help
**Code:**

> ```
> >
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>     app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
>     android:background="@color/primary"
>     android:elevation="10dp" />
>
> <ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:id="@+id/scrollView"
>     android:fillViewport="true">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
>             <LinearLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:orientation="vertical">
>
>
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:id="@+id/imgProduct"
>                     android:elevation="10dp"
>                     android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
>                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                     android:background="#ffffff" />
>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:orientation="vertical"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>                     <LinearLayout
>                         android:orientation="horizontal"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_below="@+id/view"
>                         android:showDividers="end">
>
>                         <FrameLayout
>                             android:id="@+id/frame"
>                             android:layout_width="60dp"
>                             android:layout_height="60dp">
>
>                             <ImageView
>                                 android:layout_width="60dp"
>                                 android:layout_height="60dp"
>                                 android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
>                                 android:src="@drawable/ic_action_profile_black" />
>
>                             <ImageView
>                                 android:id="@+id/circle_crop"
>                                 android:layout_width="60dp"
>                                 android:layout_height="60dp"
>                                 android:src="@drawable/circle_crop" />
>
>
>                         </FrameLayout>
>
>                         <LinearLayout
>                             android:orientation="vertical"
>                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
>
>                             <TextView
>                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                                 android:text="Medium Text"
>                                 android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
>                                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>                                 android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />
>
>                             <TextView
>                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
>                                 android:text="Small Text"
>                                 android:id="@+id/txtTime" />
>                         </LinearLayout>
>
>                     </LinearLayout>
>
>                     <TextView
>                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                         android:text="Medium Text"
>                         android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
>                         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
>                         android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />
>
>                     <TextView
>                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                         android:text="Medium Text"
>                         android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
>                         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
>
>                     <LinearLayout
>                         android:orientation="horizontal"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>                         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
>                         android:paddingRight="5dp"
>                         android:id="@+id/tagsContainer">
>
>                     </LinearLayout>
>
>                     <LinearLayout
>                         android:orientation="horizontal"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>                         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
>                         android:paddingRight="5dp">
>
>                         <TextView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                             android:text="10 Likes"
>                             android:id="@+id/txtLikes"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:textSize="16sp"
>                             android:textAlignment="center" />
>
>                         <TextView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                             android:text="10 Comments"
>                             android:id="@+id/txtComments"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:textSize="16sp"
>                             android:textAlignment="center" />
>
>                         <TextView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>                             android:text="100 Times viewed"
>                             android:id="@+id/txtViews"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:textSize="16sp"
>                             android:textAlignment="center" />
>                     </LinearLayout>
>
>                     <LinearLayout
>                         android:orientation="horizontal"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
>
>                         <ImageView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="30dp"
>                             android:id="@+id/imgLike"
>                             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_like_black"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
>
>                         <ImageView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="30dp"
>                             android:id="@+id/imgComment"
>                             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_comment_black"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
>
>                         <ImageView
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="30dp"
>                             android:id="@+id/imgShare"
>                             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share_black"
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
>
>                         <Button
>                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                             android:layout_height="30dp"
>                             android:text="Buy"
>                             android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
>                             android:background="@drawable/btncorner"
>                             android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                             android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
>                             android:elevation="10dp"
>
>                             android:layout_weight="1"
>                             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
>                     </LinearLayout>
>
>
>                 </LinearLayout>
>
>             </LinearLayout>
>         </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>             android:text="Loading Similar Products.."
>             android:id="@+id/txtSimilarProducts"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@id/feedContainer"
>             android:scrollbars="none">
>
>         </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Comment: If you want `Recyclerview` without scrollbar, why would you use `Recyclerview` in the first place? Also, please show your code and xml.

Comment: the cards i'm displaying in recyclerview contains images se to save from Out of memory exception and they can be of different heights as well. I guess this feature is supported by recyclerview only using staggeredgridlayoutmanager

Comment: i have posted my xml. please check

Answer (score 1):

For smooth scrolling you should use `<ScrollView>` instead of `<ScrollBar>`.